# Адаптив картинок в флекс-контейнере

Tags: html, css

Итак, всем снова здравствуйте, все еще воюю с адаптивом. И, к сожалению, снова вынужден спросить совета (а так хотелось понять самому). В общем, есть флекс-контейнер, слева фото, справа заголовок и текст, при уменьшении разрешения экрана заголовок и текст сползают вниз (flex-wrap:wrap), а фото остается сверху. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы фото отображалось корректно на всю ширину блока? Пытался сделать с помощью min-width - не помогло, если сделать фикс. ширину - при еще более узком экране картинка выглядит ужасно и ломает верстку. Магистры, нужна ваша сила.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu__item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}



/* --------------------------------------------------- */

.menu__content {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 100px;
    
}

/* --------------------------------------------------- */

.menu__wrapper {
    max-width: 50%;  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu__img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

@media (max-width:991px){
   
    .container {
        max-width: 750px;
    }

    .menu__item {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .menu__wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu__content {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu__img {
        min-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<section class="section">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="section__header">
            <h3 class="section__title">Меню</h3>
            <p class="section__text">КОФЕ, ЗАВТРАКИ, ВЫПЕЧКА</p>
        </div>

        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu__item">
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <img class="menu__img" src="https://picsum.photos/2500/4200" >
                </div>
                <div class="menu__content">
                    <h3 class="menu__title">Отличный кофе</h3>
                    <p class="menu__text">Наши бариста приготовят для Вас крипкий и ароматный кофе, чтобы проснуться утром. Или нежный и сладкий для поддержания энергии во время рабочего дня</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__item">
                <div class="menu__content">
                    <h3 class="menu__title">Вкуснейшие завтраки</h3>
                    <p class="menu__text">Пока бариста будут варить для вас отменный кофе, закажите наши завтраки которые не оставят вас равнадушными на весь день!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <img class="menu__img" src="https://picsum.photos/3600/4500" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu__item">
                <div class="menu__wrapper">
                    <img class="menu__img" src="https://picsum.photos/1800/2500" >
                </div>
                <div class="menu__content">
                    <h3 class="menu__title">Свежайшая вепечка</h3>
                    <p class="menu__text">Возьмите с собой или к кофе нашу свежую выпечку. Лучший вариант чтобы сделать перекус во время работы или перерыва!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

```
P.S - правда пытался разобраться сам, ведь так лучше усваивается, ведь я учусь. Поэтому, если не сложно, прошу ответить хотя бы с минимальным объяснением, что я делаю не так и почему, спасибо!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас *menu__wrapper* имеет  *max-width: 50%* , а *menu__img* находится в нем, поэтому *menu__img* работает как раз правильно, тянется на все 100% доступной ей ширины. Растяните *menu__wrapper* и спозиционируйте картинку, как вам надо. Можно к примеру *menu__wrapper* сделать фиксированной высоты, чтобы картинка не занимала много места, а саму картинку расположить при помощи **object-fit: cover**

Comment: если я делаю menu__wrapper width: 100%; - то картинка приобретает нежелательные масштабы, желательно чтобы 2 блока menu__wrapper и menu__content были равны по ширине, во имя красоты, конечно. 
А если я делаю menu__wrapper фикс. высоты, контент заползает на картинку.

Comment: @НикитаГришин Я же вам дал подсказку. Почитайте про object-fit